# How to get MVC to lookup view in nested folder

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

My knowledge of MVC and Razor is quite basic so I'm hoping its something rather simple. Basically, I have my `Controllers` as normal but my `Views` folder has a nested structure. For example, instead of:

```
Views -> Index.cshtml
```

It is like

```
Views -> BrandName -> Index.cshtml
```

I created a custom helper to work around this, but I'm not sure how it would work with query string urls? As an example here is a controller:

```
    private DataService ds = new DataService();

    //
    // GET: /Collections/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }


    //
    // GET: /Collections/Collection?id=1
    public ActionResult Collection(int id)
    {
        var collectionModel = ds.GetCollection(id);
        return View(collectionModel);
    }
```

But how do I get `ActionResult Collection` to look at:

```
Views -> Brand2 -> Collection.cshtml
```

Here is the workaround method I was using:

```
public static string ResolvePath(string pageName)
    {
        string path = String.Empty;
        //AppSetting Key=Brand
        string brand = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Brand"];

        if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(brand))
            path = "~/Views/Shared/Error.cshtml"; //Key [Brand] was not specified
        else
            path = String.Format("~/Views/{0}/{1}", brand, pageName);

        return path;
    }
```

Comment: Unclear. You've got a workaround (that mostly works) but post a very plain Controller instead?

Comment: @HenkHolterman I don't see much point proceeding with the workaround as there's probably a way to do it naturally

Comment: @HenkHolterman Don't see how the question isn't clear anyway

Comment: For instance, is it `Views/Controller/Brand1/Index.cshtml` or `Views/Brand1/Controller/Index.cshtml` ? The controller should better be there, and I think the order matters.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Its exactly as stated in the question...Views/Brand1/Index.cshtml

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the following

```
public ActionResult Collection(int id)
{
    var collectionModel = ds.GetCollection(id);
    return View("/Brand2/Collection", collectionModel);
}
```

The above code will search for the following views.

```
~/Views/Brand2/Collection.aspx
~/Views/Brand2/Collection.ascx
~/Views/Shared/Brand2/Collection.aspx
~/Views/Shared/Brand2/Collection.ascx
~/Views/Brand2/Collection.cshtml
~/Views/Brand2/Collection.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/Brand2/Collection.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/Brand2/Collection.vbhtml
```

or to be more direct

```
public ActionResult Collection(int id)
    {
        var collectionModel = ds.GetCollection(id);
        return View("~/Brand2/Collection.cshtml", collectionModel);
    }
```

Now, I want to be the first to warn you that you should never, never, never use this answer. There is a good reason for following the conventions inherent in an MVC application. Placing your files in known locations makes it easier for everyone to understand your application.

Comment: Less than ideal but +1 for job security.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this on application start by adding paths that the view engine should check like so.

```
           RazorViewEngine razorEngine = ViewEngines.Engines.OfType<RazorViewEngine>()
          .FirstOrDefault();

            List<string> viewLocationFormats = new List<string>();
            newPartialViewFormats.Add("~/Views/Shared/MyDirectory/{0}.cshtml");
            //add any other directories you want to check as well

            razorEngine.ViewLocationFormats =
                razorEngine.ViewLocationFormats.Union(viewLocationFormats).ToArray();
```

For partial views you can do similar but on the `razorEngine.PartialViewLocationFormats` property instead.